# OData returns internal server error (500) when calling a controller that not exists - on iis

Tags: c#, rest, odata

when calling for example 
http://localhost/odata/test - (no TestController implemented),

Odata return internal server error instead of 404 (Not Found).

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirm the `path="*."` in the web.config file (inside `<system.webServer> <handlers>`)

```
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
```

Comment: This seems to fix the issue at hand, but in turn, routes with a dot after the last slash do not work anymore. I have created a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60865362) about that particular catch-22.